# Using arrays with python's string.format()

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, format

How can I use `string.format()` in a fashion such that:

```
line = 'first {0}, second {1}'
print(line.format([1,2]))
```

would print `first 1 second 2`.

Comment: Note that explicitly numbering the format fields was only necessary in Python 2.6.  All modern versions of Python will do it for you, so you only need: `line = 'first {}, second {}'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [*unpack the list*](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```
>>> line = 'first {0}, second {1}'
>>> l = [1, 2]
>>> print(line.format(*l))
first 1, second 2
```

Comment: Naming variables `l` is generally best avoided to avoid confusion between `I`, `l` and `1` </pedant>